# Search functionality in C#.Net

Tags: c#, search

I am working on C#.Net project with infragistics. My project i want to implement search options, like Microsoft outlook search functionality. For that which infragistics/Winforms tool i have to use, how to implement same Microsoft office Outlook 2007 Instant Search options  in my project.

Thanks

Comment: What are you searching against? Database, Files?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [lucene.net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) search engine. Here is some basic info about this tool:

> Lucene.Net is a high performance Information Retrieval (IR) library, also known as a search engine library. Lucene.Net contains powerful APIs for creating full text indexes and implementing advanced and precise search technologies into your programs.

Comment: I think he is (at least initially) asking which UI component to use, not how to perform the actual search operation

Comment: I reffered to "how to implement same Microsoft outlook search functionality in my project" which IMHO means logic behind `search functionality`, but I must agree that other part of question asks about UI component.